# Key event not captured in Applet AFTER I've pressed one of my GUI buttons

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener

I have music Applet which uses keyboard, mouse and GUI buttons. When applet is first loaded keyboard events work fine, as do mouse events. However, after I have pressed one of my GUI buttons the mouse events still work but the keyboard events don't, and don't start working again until I refresh the applet.

After hunting around on the net I found some posible solutions, I've tried adding `button.setFocusable(true);` and `button.addKeyListener(this);` to all my buttons, and and my panels. No effect at all. I've seen recommendations for converting to a JApplet and using key binding, but surely there must be a simpler way?
Sorry for the lack of code, I've been working on this project since I was a newbie and it's a bit of a mess, and very long!

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: If you are adding `KeyListener`s to the `Applet` then that's the problem. Go for the recommendations. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
button.setFocusable(true); and button.addKeyListener(this); to all my buttons
```

For [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton) use [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) or default implementations for [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), rather than [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) (for Swing based Container and JComponents), nor using [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

EDIT

if isn't there really important reasons, don't use prehistoric `AWT Applet`, use `JApplet`, may be sufficient would be plain `JFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Try to cut the problem area out of your project and put it here. Its highly probable, than while localizing the problem area you'll find some errors already.

If your project is a mess already, then the first and the most important thing you should do, is to order it. If it is a mess for you, that means you don't understand it. So, it simply can't work. That is your first and main error.